# Python filter() function

Tags: python, input, filter

```
filter(function,  an_iter)
*If the iterable an_iter is a sequence, then the returned value is of that same type, 
otherwise the returned value is a list.*
```

I came across the above description as part of the definition for the `filter(func, a_sequence)`  function in Python.

I understand how `filter` works on a sequence type (lists, strings, tuples).  However, can you give me situations where a  non-sequence type is the `an_iter` parameter and what kind of result would form?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When it says **'non-sequence'**, it basically means generators or unordered iterables. Here is an example with `xrange`:

```
>>> filter(lambda n: n % 2, xrange(10))
[1, 3, 5, 7, 9]
```

And with a set:

```
>>> filter(lambda n: n % 2, {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9})
[1, 3, 5, 7, 9]
```

Comment: Not entirely.  `filter(lambda x: x%2, {1,2,3,4,5})` gives back a `list` because sets are not sequences.  Similarly for dicts.

Comment: For python3, it has changed.

Answer (score 5):

For python 3, the definition is changed.

From [doc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#filter)

> **filter(function, iterable)**
>
> Construct an iterator from those elements
> of iterable for which function returns true. iterable may be either a
> sequence, a container which supports iteration, or an iterator. If
> function is None, the identity function is assumed, that is, all
> elements of iterable that are false are removed.

**Example:**

```
>>> filter(lambda x: x in 'hello buddy!', 'hello world')
<filter object at 0x000002ACBEEDCB00> # filter returns object !important

>>> ''.join([i for i in filter(lambda x: x in 'hello buddy!', 'hello world')])
'hello old'

>>> [i for i in filter(lambda n: n % 2, {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9})]
[1, 3, 5, 7, 9]
```

Answer (score 0):

It may help to see the effective implementation of [`filter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#filter):

```py
def filtered(function, iterable):
    if function is None:
        return (item for item in iterable if item)
    return (item for item in iterable if function(item))
```

Another way to implement it (with the same result) is:

```py
def filtered(function, iterable):
    if function is None:
        function = bool
    return (item for item in iterable if function(item))
```

The result always is iterable.